# Reading multiple images which are in a folder in Scilab

Tags: scilab, imread

I want to read multiple images which are in a folder in Scilab. My code is:

```
I1=dir('G:\SCI\FRAME\*.jpg');
n=length(I1);
disp(n);
for i=1:n
    I2=strcat('G:\SCI\FRAME\',I1(i).name);
    I=imread(I2);
    figure(),imshow(I);
end
```

But it does not work. It shows error "invalid index".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes to correct:

1.) `length` gives the number of characters (=length) of a string, but you want to get the number of elements (=size) in a vector (the filenames), hence you should use `size`.

2.) I1 is a list structure returned by `dir`. You can extract its content with the `.` operator, e.g. `I1.name`,  `I1.date`,  `I1.bytes`,  `I1.isdir`. Type these into the consol, to see the contents! Since `I1.name` already contains the fullpath+filename+extension as a string vector, you don't have to construct it with `strcat`. Anyway if you want to "glue" 2 strings together, it's easier to use `+` e.g. `S="fisrst_string"+"second_string"`.
So the revised code:

```
I1=dir('G:\SCI\FRAME\*.jpg');
n=size(I1.name,"*");  //size of the I1.name vector
disp(n);
for i=1:n
  I=imread(I1.name(i));  //I1.name is a string vector
  figure();
  imshow(I);
end
```